# Django startproject fails: No module named zoneinfo

Tags: python, django

I am creating a new project in Django. My set up is

- Windows 10
- Django 4.0
- Python 3.8

On running `django-admin startproject myproject`, I recieve the following error:

```
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zoneinfo'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backports'
```

Any clues on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What's the output of `django-admin version`?

Comment: Try `python3.8 -m django startproject myproject`?

Comment: @IainShelvington It return 4.0 . Your second remark works indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `pip install backports.weakref` and restart server.